# RubyMotion - Joint iOS / Android development

Tags: android, ios, rubymotion, write-once

I've just gotten RubyMotion to pursue and idea. I'm trying to figure out how to "write once, run anywhere" with it - it looks like it could be possible with some appropriate abstractions, etc, but I'm not finding any guidance on the web.

Is there a known way to do this?

Comment: Separate your business logic out of the controllers and views into a helper method which is included in your controllers. From here you can essentially use the same helper file in both iOS and Android applications. This should help making the transition and updates between the two a bit nicer.

Answer (score 1):

It's still so early on in, with the android support that is, we haven't had much time to tackle this. I think that most of the sentiment in the rubymotion leans towards writing truly native apps, which drastically minimizes the amount that can be shared.

On the other hand, Canadian has shown that code *can* be shared across platforms, but when i looked at their "forms" software, I did not get the feeling that it would be feasible to build a consumer application that had native look and feel on both platforms with the same code base.

For me, the goal is to write gems and tools that have the same api on both OSes, but maintain independent Ui, and share the business/model layer across platforms.

Comment: That's fair and the impression I've gotten - it would still be excellent to have a way to maximally share code - I'm still new to this, but it looks like the platform-specific code will mostly be UI, leaving me with all the model logic that *should* be cross-platform.